# JQUERY - get method not returning data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new to jquery and building an app using phonegap and jquery mobile.I have to load the data from a page and prepare a nested collapsible list view and present it to the user.I have written code for everything except that i don't know how to get the data from the server.
I am trying to use $.get method and in the callback of that method trying to prepare the collapsible list view from the returned server data.But the problem is this piece of code which returns the status as success but data as null

```
  <body>

 <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
 <div data-role="header">
  <h1>My Commodities</h1>
 </div>

 <script>

 $.get(" //URL to be called",function(data,status){
 alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
 });
 </script>
 </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Image http://tinypic.com/r/fav6g1/8

Comment: Um, looks like the data is there....Use `console.log()`, not alert

Comment: The server is returning an Object that is not necessarily a string - perhaps JSON? You just need to parse the results instead of using an `alert()`.

Comment: cannot use console.log as the data is fetched from other domain and the browser gives error.

Answer (score 5):

Its returning data(see the [Object object] thing in the alert)

Your code is working fine.

Try console.log(data) instead of alert, and check the data in the console

Answer (score 0):

The data is not `null`, it's in object format! Use `console.log()` to view what properties it has, or loop through it, or if it's JSON, parse it!

You can use `Object.keys(data)`, `console.log(data)`, or even (not really recommended but not necessarily bad), `foreach (derp in data)`, or if it's JSON, use `JSON.parse(data)`.

Comment: Actually the data returned is JSON. I know it for sure.The problem doesn't solve even if i use getJSON method instead.Added to this the browsers doesn't fetch the urls as I access the url from some other domain.The only way is to check through emulator.